# Silverlight Datagrid: Highlight an entire column when that column is sorted

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in my Silverlight application that I would like to highlight an entire column when that column is sorted.

It's similar in concept to this previous question: [Silverlight DataGrid: Highlight an entire column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829846/silverlight-datagrid-highlight-an-entire-column).

Any ideas? I've thought maybe attaching a behavior to the LayoutUpdated event and checking a cell to see if it's in a sorted column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues that you have to get around to do what you want to do.  The biggest issue is that finding out when a column is sorted is a lot harder then it should be.  The only way I have ever found to identify that a column was sorted to make `DataGrid.ItemsSource` a PagedCollectionView and listen to the `CollectionChanged` event on its `SortDescriptions` property.  If you use a `PagedCollectionView` for your ItemsSource and all columns that can be sorted on are `DataGridBoundColumn` (really any of the premades other than TemplateColumn) then this behavior should be fairly close to what you want to do.

```
public class DataGridSortedColumnHighlightBehavior : Behavior<DataGrid>
{

    private List<DataGridRow> rows = new List<DataGridRow>();

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.LoadingRow += AssociatedObject_LoadingRow;
        AssociatedObject.UnloadingRow += AssociatedObject_UnloadingRow;

        if (AssociatedObject.ItemsSource == null)
        {
            AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated += AssociatedObject_LayoutUpdated;
        }
        else
        {
            var collection =
                ((AssociatedObject.ItemsSource as PagedCollectionView).SortDescriptions as INotifyCollectionChanged);
            collection.CollectionChanged += DataGridSortedColumnHighlightBehavior_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    void AssociatedObject_UnloadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        rows.Remove(e.Row);
    }

    void AssociatedObject_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        rows.Add(e.Row);
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AssociatedObject.ItemsSource != null)
        {
            AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated -= AssociatedObject_LayoutUpdated;
            var collection =
                ((AssociatedObject.ItemsSource as PagedCollectionView).SortDescriptions as INotifyCollectionChanged);
            collection.CollectionChanged += DataGridSortedColumnHighlightBehavior_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    void DataGridSortedColumnHighlightBehavior_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach(SortDescription sortDesc in e.NewItems)
            {
                foreach(var column in AssociatedObject.Columns)
                {
                    var boundColumn = column as DataGridBoundColumn;
                    if (boundColumn == null)
                        continue;
                    if (boundColumn.Binding.Path.Path == sortDesc.PropertyName)
                    {
                        foreach (var row in rows)
                            ColorCell(column,row,Colors.Red);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach(SortDescription sortDesc in e.OldItems)
            {
                foreach(var column in AssociatedObject.Columns)
                {
                    var boundColumn = column as DataGridBoundColumn;
                    if (boundColumn == null)
                        continue;
                    if (boundColumn.Binding.Path.Path == sortDesc.PropertyName)
                    {
                        foreach (var row in rows)
                            ColorCell(column,row,Colors.White);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ColorCell(DataGridColumn column, DataGridRow item, Color color )
    {
        var content = column.GetCellContent(item);
        if (content == null)
            return;

        var parent = GetParent<DataGridCell>(content);

        if (parent != null)
            parent.Background = new SolidColorBrush(color);

    }

    public static T GetParent<T>(DependencyObject source)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(source);
        while (parent != null && !typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(parent.GetType()))
        {
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }
        return (T)parent;
    }        
}
```

Comment: That works almost perfectly. Thanks much for your answer, the only one thing I've noticed is that it sometimes has a problem with scrolling, but its still a very big help!

Comment: The scrolling issue is caused by the way the `DataGrid` virtualizes rows.  It only keeps instantiates the number of rows visible on the screen plus 1 and keeps those in memory.  To fix the issue you probably need to modify the code to keep a list of the columns that are sorted and in the LoadingRow event handler highlight the cells for those columns.

Comment: Yeap thats the exact route that I took. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way
http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/highlighting-entire-column-in-datagrid/